# NVIDIA-SMI not working, struggle with installing the right cuda for my driver on dell inspiron fresh ubuntu 20

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, dell, cuda, hybrid-graphics

My laptop is Dell Inspiron  with Ubuntu 18.4 LTS, after trying to run Cuda with NVIDIA GForce 820m my device stopped booting to the GUI and kept looping in a black screen with the message "created slice user slice" and another line with "UID 21".

So I got into GRUB and purged all nvidia drivers and cuda then reinstalled driver 390 which was recommended in journalctl error.

### I didn't succeed and I had to format my device and downloaded ubuntu 20.04 LTS instead. Now my GUI is good but I still need cuda and nvidia to return to my work.

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

shows:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible     controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:56 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff



  *-display
   description: 3D controller
   product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:57 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

The "Software & Updates" > "Additional Drivers" shows:

https://ibb.co/ctYfGK5

So I know that I need to download cuda for product GF117M which I have, but I am very confused about the nvidia card names; is it 820m or GF117M ? what should I download to work with my system?

NVIDIA-smi shows:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't     communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure      that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and     running.
```

messing with the graphic card files already costed me a whole OS so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Thank God I fixed the issue after a lot of search !
Here's what I did exactly:

#To get connected to the card, you need to get the exact same model of your GPU
#Use the command: sudo lshw -C video

#My card is GF117M==> GeForce 100M series
#Download the driver of it from nvidia website: https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Now; it's clear what I should do with cuda too; the same exact steps: searching for the proper version of CUDA for the "GF 100M series" and download it and I'm good to go !

**-------UPDATE------**

I completed the driver installation and NVIDIA-SMI works finally; this is the result:
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.108    Driver Version: 340.108        |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 820M        Off  | 0000:08:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    113MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
So I moved to the next step which is getting "CUDA". I checked this link to find out about the compatibility of my driver with CUDA:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus
From that link, I chose "legacy drivers" since my GPU is quite old:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus
My GPU is not listed there, so I'm depressed a little -_- but my machine is from 2013-2014 so...
It's good to know though and it's good to fix :) at least I know more info about my device and I fixed a very big confusion for me that costed me a whole OS a week back.
I hope you find it useful**

Comment: So you found the Nvidia 340 driver works for you?  That's available in the standard repositories.

Comment: @ubfan1 I purged it while trying to update my ubuntu 18 and ignorantly thought that driver 450 works for me. My system was only obeying the mess I made: my own standard repository for NVIDIA was corrupted. So simply the solution was to purge everything related to NVIDIA, find my card model, download the proper driver for it from the nvidia site, download CUDA if the card supports it too (mine doesn't support it)

Comment: Actually the 820m is listed under current GPUs, has a compute capability of 2.1, which should be capable of running CUDA 8.0.  Later CUDA releases require a higher compute capability, but most of the samples will run.

Comment: @ubfan1 you are right I did find CUDA for GEFORCE 820M but the page displays: https://www.nvidia.com/en-me/geforce/gaming-laptops/geforce-820m/ 
[Even AI can't find this page!] . Was this page removed or something?

Comment: Search this site for 820m, and see what others have done.  The 340 driver is easily installed, the 390 takes a little more work, but is possible when nvidia-driver-390 is selected -- all from standard repos.  Can't say what/why Nvidia is doing.

Comment: @ubfan1 driver 390 is not compatible with a card from the 100M series like mine. I did try it before the 450 and it failed to communicate with the GPU, maybe that's why nvidia removed the CUDA page for it. I'm thinking they removed it because of problems like the one I had..it's strange since there is no report about the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115076/discussion-between-ubfan1-and-mohammed-baashar).